# How to design UILabel?

Tags: ios, uilabel

I want to make the exact label like the picture. Do I need to use 3 labels for that? If I use 3 labels then how to reduce the gap between the 3 labels?

[image: The image of label]

Comment: `UILabel`s seem like a good choice but the exact number required depends on how you intend to use them. Use Autolayout to position the `UILabels`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you truly mean, but if they were 3 separate labels, would you not just move some higher up to reduce the gap between them by increasing the `position.y` of the lower labels?